# How do I fix my DELL Studio 1535 audio ports?

Tags: hardware-failure, headphone-jack, dell-studio

for a while, my audio ports have been acting up.
I have 3, one is mic and two are headphones. The two headphone ports do not work properly and I have to spin and wiggle the audio jack inside the port to make contact which is like fishing while blindfolded.

I wish to fix it myself since I have a background in IT but cannot find a proper tutorial for that particular component.

My warranty expired and I don't have a DELL service near me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would rather need a background in electronics and more specifically soldering if you want to fix this, your IT experience doesn't really matter.

The audio connectors are soldered on your laptop's motherboard and probably look like this.

[image: Audio connector image].

You'll need to carefully de-solder the faulty ones and replace them - you can buy them at any electronic components store, they should be pretty standard (just make sure that the pinout and the solder points are in the same place).

If you need more help about this I'd recommend you take pictures of the board and the broken connectors and ask on [Electronics Stack Exchange](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/).

**However I don't recommend attempting this unless you have very good soldering skills. It'll be safer and cheaper to just buy a USB sound card rather than risking to damage the entire motherboard.**